# How to format date from timestamp in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database row whose type is "timestamp". It automatically populates each time a new record has been added with the time of that record's insertion. Right now for one of the records it holds the value:

```
2010-06-19 18:40:51
```

I tried to turn this in to a more user friendly format by:

```
$timeStamp = $row['date'];
$timeStamp = date( "m/d/Y", $timeStamp);
```

But it returns this:

```
12/31/1969
```

I read somewhere that the date function can only be used on unix timestamps, perhaps what I have in my database isn't a proper timestamp and I need to convert it to one first before using the date function on it (?). What is the solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function:

```
$timeStamp = $row['date'];
$timeStamp = date( "m/d/Y", strtotime($timeStamp));
```

For the date from your example `2010-06-19 18:40:51`, it would return:

```
06/19/2010
```

The `timestamp` field updates automatically but you can disable that behavior by changing it to `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` otherwise it will auto update. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> In a CREATE TABLE  statement, the first TIMESTAMP column can be declared in any of the following ways:
>
> With both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses, the column has the current timestamp for its default value, and is automatically updated.
>
> With neither DEFAULT nor ON UPDATE clauses, it is the same as DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
>
> With a DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  clause and no ON UPDATE clause, the column has the current timestamp for its default value but is not automatically updated.

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime($timeStamp)` (string to time) is what you want to convert into a unix timestamp.

Then you can use the date on that, so something like `date( "m/d/Y", strtotime($timeStamp) )`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(sql_row_with_timestamp) AS some_much_more_readable_name FROM your_table` should do the trick.