# How to format date with carbon format() before converting to json

Tags: php, json, laravel, date

l have a function in the dashboard controller

```
  public function chart(){

    $result = DB::table('orders')->pluck('total_price','created_at');
    return response()->json($result);
}
```

it feeds this jquery script

```
public function chart(){

    $result = DB::table('orders')->pluck('total_price','created_at');
  // $result['created_at'] = $result['created_at']->format('M d Y');
    return response()->json($result);
}
```

Currently the graph displays but how can l format the date to use format('M d Y') instead of the timestamp that it shows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format date from timestamp in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080921/how-to-format-date-from-timestamp-in-php)

Comment: Please give an example of the json output you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the date format Laravel outputs to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074356/how-do-i-change-the-date-format-laravel-outputs-to-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved if you use [Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) instead of directly access the database.

Eloquent implement [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor), a kind of function that transforms your data to the wanted format.

**BUT**, actually, you shouldn't use it to this purpose, instead, you can use [Eloquent API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources), so you can create a resource that transforms the data as your want.

Sorry if this answer is very conceptual, but I think that using the correct tools to the framework is the right way to solve your problem. That's the magic of a framework. Good Luck!

Comment: l am struggling selecting just two columns using eloquent..can you please tell me how

Comment: `MyModel::select(['column'])->get()`

Comment: you are the best bro..it worked like a charm.. one last issue am having on the graph is when l refresh the graph l need to resize the page before the graph data shows..do you know why..

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to achieve this: Carbon is a simple PHP API extension for DateTime.

```
<?php
    \Carbon\Carbon::parse($result['created_at'])->format('M d Y');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel Eloquent and then try with Carbon string formatting option :

Add the following to fetch the value in your view blade file.

```
{{  $result->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }}
```